# Best method to drive SPI over 1 m

Tags: spi, driver, differential

In my current project I need to control 8 analog multiplier. They are controlled with SPI but without the MISO line, so I would need to route :

- SCK
- MOSI
- 8 slaves selects

So 10 signals in total. The 8 analog multiplier are 1 meter away from the microcontroller, on another PCB. I need to ensure those signals would be rugged against noise. There is no slave to master communication.

I also have two main concerns : power consumption and available space...

What is the best solution ?

At first I was thinking of using RS-485 IC but that would require two many components...

Thanks

Comment: if all 8 slaves are on the same PCB, and speed isn't too much of an issue, then you may only need one select line, if the slaves are daisy-chained. 'Rugged against noise' is not a specification. If you have particular interference sources, or measured levels, then say what they are in the question. A normal treatment of the transmission line nature of the wires from master to slaves is good enough for most situations.

Comment: *What is the best solution* is not definable. Start building up a list of constraints.

Comment: What are your SPI speed and voltage level? Is this a one-time setup or do you need to build multiple of those? Why is power consumption a concern in the context of SPI?

Comment: Another option could be to have another (cheap) microcontroller on the remote PCB, that would give you more choice for the link between the two parts of the system. But at a price of added complexity.

Comment: Consider accepting an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1m is not that much. Even in noisy environment good shielding and low speed should be enough to achieve reliable communication. That is, unless you are going to run this thing next to aircraft radar or ark welder.

A simple solution would be to use shielded CAT5/6 cable. One twisted pair would be SCK+GND, another MOSI+GND, and the remaining 4 can be used for 3-bit slave address and enable line. You'd need a shielded jack on master side, of course.

On the slave PCB a 3-to-8 decoder, like [74HC138D](https://www.digikey.ca/product-detail/en/toshiba-semiconductor-and-storage/74HC138D/74HC138DCT-ND/5879971) will convert 4 control lines into low level on one (or none) of the 8 output pins, suitable for direct connection to !CS inputs.

And if you ever decide to increase speed or noise immunity, you can always convert those two signal+gnd pairs into differential lines, as @User323693 suggested. There are convenient dual driver/receiver chips like [SN65LVDS9638](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/sn65lvds31.pdf) and [SN65LVDT9637B](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/sn65lvds9637b.pdf) for this. There is no need to modify address control lines in this case, although you'd have to connect shield to the ground on slave board too.

Answer (score 0):

One meter, with a very good shielded cable may work.  Since the slave select pins are basically DC lines, you can try it for sure. But you still have to care about the clock and the data lines. Opt for lower frequency as much as possible. I had interfaced 14 SPI lines from a mother board to all the daughter boards an about 50 cm of length. i had used MLVDS at that time.

Going for a LVDS option is really a good idea, though components' count increase a bit.  You will have better immunity and can achieve speed too.